# Spring Boot Connect to mysql docker

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, database-connection

I have spun up the `mysql` docker image.

From `docker ps`:

`bcb0a900b693        mysql:latest        "docker-entrypoint..."   5 hours ago         Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp   chrisbolton`

I have created a basic `spring boot` project where I have created a simple class.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class ChrisboltonServiceApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ChrisboltonServiceApplication.class, args);
}

@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@RequestMapping("/hello")
public String sayHello(){
    return "Hello";
}

@RequestMapping(path="/blogs")
public @ResponseBody Iterable<ChrisBolton> getAllUsers() {
    List<ChrisBolton> result = jdbcTemplate.query(
            "SELECT * FROM blog",
            (rs, rowNum) -> new ChrisBolton(rs.getString("author"), 
                                               rs.getString("title"), 
                                               rs.getString("content"), 
                                               rs.getDate("date"))
    );

    return result;
}
```

}

I have placed my configuration in my `application.properties`

```
spring.main.banner-mode=off

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=opening
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

When I start my app, I am able to hit `localhost:8080/hello` which returns `Hello!`

When I hit `localhost:8080/blogs`, I get this error

`java.sql.SQLException: No database selected`

So I guess I don't understand how the `autowired` is completely working.

I have tried looking into `beans` or maybe using the `Connection` class. But what is the correct `Spring Boot` way of connecting to my `mysql` instance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like your missing the database name, for example the database named test:

`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test`

Hope it helps

Comment: When I do that I get an error because: "Communications link failure", how do I use a mysql docker container in Springboot, is it an other url because I am on windows?

Answer (score 4):

The problem that you are facing is because you aren't providing the database name, you can't do a query for a whole server therefore.

Wrong format:

> spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306

Right Format:

> spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/accounts

The general format is like this

> jdbc:[Database Type]://[Host Resolver]:[Port]/[Database Name]